# How to add a space between alphanumeric and non alphanumeric characters?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

If a word contains alphanumeric characters and the first character or characters is (or are) non-alphanumeric, then how to split off each such leading non-alphanumeric character as a separate word; Whether or not the first rule was applied, if the word contains alphanumeric characters and the last character or characters is (or are) non-alphanumeric, then how to split off each such trailing non-alphanumeric character as a separate word?

For example, if I have a

```
string = "John had a meeting with 3managers! %nervous:( t^ria7 #manager's.!"
```

The output should look like this

```
"John had a meeting with 3managers ! % nervous : ( t^ria7 # managers's . !"
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: I tried using this re.sub(r'(\W)(\w)', r'\1 \2', string) But the problem with this is it adds spaces between all words and it does not fulfill both rules.

Comment: Is installing another lib an option?

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: Updated my answer with an easier solution.

Comment: How do I add the following rules to the same question? a.  If the token ends with "'s" (apostrophe, followed by the letter s), then split the token into two tokens: the part preceding the apostrophe, and the token "'s";

b. If the token end with "n't" (n-apostrophe-t), then split the token into two tokens: the part preceding the "n", and the token "not";

c. If the token end with "'m" (apostrophe-m), then split the token into two tokens: the part preceding the apostrophe, and the token "am"; and

d. If none of the preceding sub-rules applies, then accept the token as it is.

Comment: I'd phrase another question and would link to this one.

Comment: Ok I will do that. I am new here so learning how to use it. Thank you very much for your reply/answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The (new) idea is to split the words by whitespaces and then to apply an alternative regex to each word. In the end, the parts are glued together again.
The expression in question:

```
^(\W+)|(\W+)$
```

Which is either non-word characters from the beginning or the end of the string, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/h4k5u0/1).

---

In `Python`, you need to check which group was captured to insert the appropriate whitespaces:

```
import re

string = """John had a meeting with 3managers! %nervous:( t^ria7 #manager's."""

def replacer(match):
    if match.group(1) is not None:
        return '{} '.format(match.group(1))
    else:
        return ' {}'.format(match.group(2))

rx = re.compile(r'^(\W+)|(\W+)$')

string = " ".join([rx.sub(replacer, word) for word in string.split()])
print(string)
```

This yields

```
John had a meeting with 3managers ! % nervous :( t^ria7 # manager's .
```

---

Comment: How do I add a space between two non alphanumeric characters in the same code. For example, to get the output like  John had a meeting with 3managers ! % nervous : ( t^ria7 # manager's . "    Here there is a space between : and (    and space between . and  "