# How do I add the following rules to "How to add a space between alphanumeric and non alphanumeric characters?"

Tags: regex, python-3.x

[How to add a space between alphanumeric and non alphanumeric characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48370985/how-to-add-a-space-between-alphanumeric-and-non-alphanumeric-characters?noredirect=1#comment83730611_48370985)

How do I add the following rules to the same question?

- If the token ends with "'s" (apostrophe, followed by the letter
  s), then split the token into two tokens: the part preceding the
  apostrophe, and the token "'s"
- If the token end with "n't" (n-apostrophe-t), then split the token into two tokens: the part preceding the "n", and the token "not"
- If the token end with "'m" (apostrophe-m), then split the token into two tokens: the part preceding the apostrophe, and the token "am"
- If none of the preceding sub-rules applies, then accept the token as it is.

Here is what I have tried:

```
def replacer(match):
    if match.group(1).endswith("'s"):
        return '{} '.format(match.group(1) + "'s")
    elif match.group(2).endswith("n't"):
        return '{} '.format(match.group(2) + "not")
    elif match.group(3).endswith("'m"):
        return '{} '.format(match.group(3) + "'m")
    else:
        return '{}'.format(match.group(4))
rx = re.compile(r'("\'s" | "n\'t" | "\'m")+$')

string = " ".join([rx.sub(replacer, word) for word in string.split()])
print(string)
```

Comment: People here are generally more willing to help if you post what **you** have been trying to achieve your aim.

Comment: I have been trying this figure out my own, but I don't seem to get closer to my goal here.

Comment: rx = re.compile(r'("\'s" | "n\'t" | "\'m")+$')
def replacer(match):
    if match.group(1) == rx:
        return '{} '.format(match.group(1) + "'s")
    elif match.group(2) == rx:
     return '{} '.format(match.group(2) + "not")
    elif match.group(3) == rx:
     return '{} '.format(match.group(3) + "am")
    else:
        return ' {}'.format(match.group(4))

string = " ".join([rx.sub(replacer, word) for word in string.split()])
print(string)

Comment: Where do you see my error is in this code? Am I in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combined with the other answer:

```
import re

string1 = "John's boat hasn't any comfort. I'm pretty sure he'll sell it soon."
string2 = """John had a meeting with 3managers! %nervous:( t^ria7 #manager's."""

def replacer(item):
    if item.endswith("'s"):
        return (item[:-2],) + ("'s",)
    elif item.endswith("n't"):
        return (item[:-3],) + ("not",)
    elif item.endswith("'m"):
        return (item[:-2],) + ("am",)
    else:
        rx = re.compile(r'^(?P<nonword1>\W+)(?P<word1>.*)$|(?P<word2>.*)(?P<nonword2>\W+)$')
        match = rx.search(item)
        if match is None:
            return (item,)

        if match.group('nonword1') is not None:
            return ('{} '.format(match.group('nonword1')), match.group('word1'),)
        else:
            return (match.group('word2'), ' {}'.format(match.group('nonword2')),)

""" tests """
parts = [token for item in string1.split() for token in replacer(item)]
new_string = " ".join(parts)
print(new_string)

parts = [token for item in string2.split() for token in replacer(item)]
new_string = " ".join(parts)
print(new_string)
```

This yields

```
John 's boat has not any comfort  . I am pretty sure he'll sell it soon  .
John had a meeting with 3managers  ! %  nervous:( t^ria7 #  manager's.
```

Comment: I was following the similar pattern/logic. Thank you very much for your help.